# Lightview with tinymce

Tags: tinymce, inline, lightbox

guys...

I am trying to use `lightview` and `tinymce` together.

While testing simple things, I could'nt to reproduce a call to render tinymce using `inline` **type** in `lightview`.

e.g:

```
             Lightview.show({
                url: "contentPageArea",
                type: "inline",
                options: {
                    closeButton: false,
                    evalScripts: true,
                    afterUpdate: function (element, position) {
                       console.log("after");
                       tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'txtAreaContentPage');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it just using this method:

```
function removeTinyMCE() {
  tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'txtAreaContentPage');
  tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'txtAreaContentPage');
}
```

and calling before **addControl**

```
afterUpdate: function (element, position) {
                removeTinyMCE();
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'txtAreaContentPage');
            }
```